# convert iterative function to recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion, iteration

i have a problem on iterative function and recursive function.
i have a iterative function and i have to convert it into a recursive one.
could you give me some advice on my code?thanks so much

the code is to determine if the array of data points correspond to a concave function using recursion.

Here is the code of the iterative version:

```
bool isConcave(double a[], int n)
{
int slope = 1;
bool concave = true;

for (int i = 1; i < n && concave; i++)
{
    double delta = a[i] - a[i-1];

    if (slope > 0)
    {
        if (delta < 0)
            slope = -1;
    }
    else if (delta > 0)  
        concave = false; // slope == -1 and delta > 0
}
return concave;
}
```

And, here is the code of my recursive version which can't work:

```
bool isConcave_r(double a[], int n, int& slope)  
{
//Implement this function using recursion
double delta = a[n] - a[n-1];
bool concave = true;

if (n == 0)
    return false;
if (slope > 0)
{
    if (delta < 0)
    {
        slope = -1;
    }
    else
        concave = true;
}else
    return 0;

//dummy return statement
return isConcave_r(a, n, slope);

}
```

Comment: You use a slope variable that is updated in your iterative loop. You should probably have this variable as an argument in your recursive algorithm. But I can see instantly that both function will not behave identically : look at what the result is when n is 0.

Comment: @Paddyd the output of the program should be the same as the output given by the iterative version.  But now it isn't.

Comment: Your recursive function always returns `false/0`, slope value is not used in the 'loop' of recursion, `concave` is useless too (always true, never checked). `delta` is computed before `n` check, trivial case n==0, n==1 are not good.

Comment: Note also that your recursive function loops in backward order, and iterative in forward order...

Comment: Why do you want to write the recursive function ?

Comment: @Jarod42 it is the requirement of my code

Answer (score 0):

Not necessary the best/cleanest way, but you may replace any loop

```
for (int i = 0; i != N; ++i) {
    body(i, localVars);
}
```

by

```
void body_rec(int N, int i, LocalVars& localVars)
{
    if (i == N) return;
    body(i, localvars);
    body_rec(N, i + 1, localVars);
}
```

or

```
int body_rec(int N, int i, LocalVars& localVars)
{
    if (i == N) return localVars.res; // or any correct value
    body(i, localvars);
    if (localVars.end) { // break the "loop", and so stop the recursion.
        return localVars.res; // or any correct value
    }
    return body_rec(N, i + 1, localVars);
}
```

So, in your case, you forget to pass `slope` into the recursion.

[edit]

Full solution:

```
bool isConcave_r(int N, int i, double a[], int slope)
{
    if (i >= N) return true;

    const double delta = a[i] - a[i-1];

    if (slope > 0) {
        if (delta < 0) {
            slope = -1;
        }
    }
    else if (delta > 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return isConcave_r(N, i + 1, a, slope);
}

bool isConcave(double a[], int n)
{
    int i = 1;
    int slope = 1;
    return isConcave_r(n, i, a, slope);
}
```

Note also that the name seems "incorrect", you don't check if the "curve" is concave, case where `delta == 0` should be specific I think...

Comment: May I ask a question? In your example, it is in void type.  If the same technique is used to deal with Boolean type, how to deal with it?

Comment: Added a sample to show a possible way to handle return value and break.

Comment: when i pass the variable slope into the recursion, it is still the same as before...

Comment: As I wrote in comment, your recursive function have several problems, I think I've gave you enough info to progress. You may post the modified recursive function with all fixes for other fixes if needed.

Answer (score 0):

In the iterative version of your program, the computation moves from 1 to n-1, but in the recursive version computation moves form n-1 to 1. So, instead of tail recursion, use head recursion. And slope should be static variable. So, declare slope as static variable. It will work.

Comment: Order is not the most important problem (if it is in his case). Using `static slope` is ugly, the function will not be thread safe and will force it to reset the value on exit to allow a second call...